# Create a list from two lists based on values in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, merge

```
list1=['String-1', 'String-2', 'String-1', 'String-1', 'String-2', 'String-2', 'String-1', 'String-2', 'String-1', 'String-2']
list2=['TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1']
list3=['TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2']
```

i want to construct list 4 from list2 and list3 based on the values in list1
if value in list1=String-1 then pick from list2 else pick from list3

```
finallist=['TEXT-1', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-2']
```

Any help?

Comment: zip function may be useful here.

Comment: Please show your attempt, and how it doesn't work.

Comment: there are 5 `'String-2'` items but the length of `list3` is 4. You don't have enough items to go ...

Comment: You are already explaining the algorithm, so what is missing is your attempt of the implementation of that algorithm.

Comment: Question is unclear but probably `list4 = [x[1] if x[0][:8] == "String-1" else x[2] for x in zip(list1, list2, list3)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
list1=['String-1', 'String-2', 'String-1', 'String-1', 'String-2', 'String-2', 'String-1', 'String-2', 'String-1', 'String-2']
list2=['TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1', 'TEXT-1']
list3=['TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2', 'TEXT-2']

list2chosen,list3chosen = 0,0
finallist = []
for n in list1:
    if n == "String-1":
        finallist.append(list2[list2chosen])
        list2chosen += 1
    elif n == "String-2":
        finallist.append(list3[list3chosen])
        list3chosen += 1

print(finallist)
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You could make it a bit more pythonic:`it2, it3 = iter(list2), iter(list3)
list4 = [next(it2) if x == "String-1" else next(it3) for x in list1]` only works if list2 & 3 have enough data

Comment: @FujiApple Works perfectly! I didn't know about both iter() and next(). Thanks

Comment: Use `next(it2, None)` etc to make sure it doesn't give an error if the lists don't have enough data, as in your example

Comment: Example had a typo, sum of items in list2 and list3 is always equal to items in list1, hence your solution is so far the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
finallist = [list2[0] if i == "String-1" else list3[0] for i in list1]
print(finallist)
```

Comment: That only works if every item in list2 and list3 are the same

Comment: The answer is very logical and correct but the items in both list2 and list3 are not same. My question was ambiguous somehow! Thanks for answering though.